# Case Insensitivity on Wikipedia API Calls

Tags: search, wikipedia, case-insensitive, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am attempting to add case-insensitivity to my Wikipedia api calls. Wikipedia is case-sensitive in how it names pages. So, `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat` will yield a page about the animal, `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT` will yield a disambiguation page, and `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAt` will yield a notification that the page doesn't exist.

My current problem is that I would like to use the API to return pages the same way Wikipedia does. I am currently using the following API call in Python:

```
"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=" + topic + "&action=render"
```

When searching on Wikipedia using the GUI's search box, "cat" and "CAt" will return the page about the animal, while "cAT" and "CAT" will return the disambiguation page.

How can I replicate this behavior through the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case insensitive search is done through the [Opensearch API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch).

Comment: case sensitive, or insensitive? The OP was asking for sensitive.

Comment: No they weren't. In any case, the search box uses the Opensearch API internally.